# how to run custom login page in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have written the spring security xml file and login.jsp , controller. but still can't run it. I got 404 error. How to i need to add or config in xml.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add definition like following to your spring context.

```
<security:http>
<security:form-login login-page='/login' authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed=true"/> 
<security:logout />
</security:http>
```

You also have to define the URL patterns using `<security:intercept-url>`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom controller.

You only need a JSP(x) that submit the two values

- `j_username`
- `j_password`

and need to change the configuration to use the form

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>
  <form-login  login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
...
```

Important: you need not authenticated access for the `login-page` as well as the `login-processing-url`!

- login-page == the page that is displayed when the user needs to enter his username and password
- login-processing-url == the user to which the user name and password is submitted

login.jspx:

```
<spring:url value="/static/j_spring_security_check" var="form_url" />
<form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST">
   <input type='text' name='j_username' />
   <input type='password' name='j_password' " />
   <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
</form>
```